# XCode PCH Errors

Tags: objective-c, xcode, build-error, pch

From what I can tell, this has not been asked before. I am building a cocoa touch static library and I have been going along fine until yesterday, right after I checked the project into SVN, it no longer builds and I have 36 errors in my PCH. This is all my PCH is, and I have found no problems with it in the past:

```
//
// Prefix header for all source files of the 'CocoaTouchStaticLibrary' target in the 'CocoaTouchStaticLibrary' project.
//

#ifdef __OBJC__
    #import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#endif
```

And I get these errors:

```
Build MYPROJECT of project MYPROJECT with configuration Release
ProcessPCH /var/folders/rQ/rQtcY0wvHECcTKEGF6D4hk+++TI/-Caches-/com.apple.Xcode.501/SharedPrecompiledHeaders/MYPROJECTPrefix-agsnbtjqunzmxwghwaudmojjbbgk/MYPROJECT_Prefix.pch.gch MYPROJECT_Prefix.pch normal i386 objective-c com.apple.compilers.gcc.4_2
cd /Users/rross/Documents/MYPROJECT
setenv LANG en_US.US-ASCII
setenv PATH "/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/usr/bin:/Developer/usr/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin"
/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/usr/bin/gcc-4.2 -x objective-c-header -arch i386 -fmessage-length=0 -pipe -std=c99 -Wno-trigraphs -fpascal-strings -fasm-blocks -Os -Wreturn-type -Wunused-variable -D__IPHONE_OS_VERSION_MIN_REQUIRED=30200 -isysroot /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator4.0.sdk -mmacosx-version-min=10.6 -gdwarf-2 -fobjc-abi-version=2 -fobjc-legacy-dispatch -iquote /Users/rross/Documents/MYPROJECT-iOS/build/MYPROJECT.build/Release-iphonesimulator/MYPROJECT.build/-generated-files.hmap -I/Users/rross/Documents/MYPROJECT/build/MYPROJECT.build/Release-iphonesimulator/MYPROJECT.build/-own-target-headers.hmap -I/Users/rross/Documents/MYPROJECT/build/MYPROJECT.build/Release-iphonesimulator/MYPROJECT.build/-all-target-headers.hmap -iquote /Users/rross/Documents/MYPROJECT/build/MYPROJECT.build/Release-iphonesimulator/MYPROJECT.build/-project-headers.hmap -F/Users/rross/Documents/MYPROJECT/build/Release-iphonesimulator -I/Users/rross/Documents/MYPROJECT/build/Release-iphonesimulator/include -I/Users/rross/Documents/MYPROJECT/build/MYPROJECT.build/Release-iphonesimulator/MYPROJECT.build/DerivedSources/i386 -I/Users/rross/Documents/MYPROJECT/build/MYPROJECT.build/Release-iphonesimulator/MYPROJECT.build/DerivedSources -c /Users/rross/Documents/MYPROJECT/_Prefix.pch -o /var/folders/rQ/rQtcY0wvHECcTKEGF6D4hk+++TI/-Caches-/com.apple.Xcode.501/SharedPrecompiledHeaders/_Prefix-agsnbtjqunzmxwghwaudmojjbbgk/_Prefix.pch.gch

In file included from /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator4.0.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/UIKit.framework/Headers/UIKit.h:9,
                 from /Users/rross/Documents/MYPROJECT/src/ross/util/../ui/Comparable.h:9,
                 from /Users/rross/Documents/MYPROJECT/src/ross/datatype/Time.h:11,
                 from /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator4.0.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/CoreFoundation.framework/Headers/CoreFoundation.h:26,
                 from /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator4.0.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/Foundation.framework/Headers/Foundation.h:6,
                 from /Users/rross/Documents/MYPROJECT/_Prefix.pch:6:
/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator4.0.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/UIKit.framework/Headers/UIAccelerometer.h:16: error: cannot find interface declaration for 'NSObject', superclass of 'UIAcceleration'
/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator4.0.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/UIKit.framework/Headers/UIAccelerometer.h:18: error: expected specifier-qualifier-list before 'NSTimeInterval'
/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator4.0.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/UIKit.framework/Headers/UIAccelerometer.h:22: error: expected specifier-qualifier-list before 'NSTimeInterval'
/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator4.0.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/UIKit.framework/Headers/UIAccelerometer.h:29: error: cannot find interface declaration for 'NSObject', superclass of 'UIAccelerometer'
/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator4.0.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/UIKit.framework/Headers/UIAccelerometer.h:31: error: expected specifier-qualifier-list before 'NSTimeInterval'
/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator4.0.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/UIKit.framework/Headers/UIAccelerometer.h:41: error: expected specifier-qualifier-list before 'NSTimeInterval'
/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator4.0.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/UIKit.framework/Headers/UIAccelerometer.h:46: error: cannot find protocol declaration for 'NSObject'
In file included from /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator4.0.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/UIKit.framework/Headers/UIAccessibility.h:14,
                 from /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator4.0.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/UIKit.framework/Headers/UIKit.h:10,
                 from /Users/rross/Documents/MYPROJECT/src/ross/util/../ui/Comparable.h:9,
                 from /Users/rross/Documents/MYPROJECT/src/ross/datatype/Time.h:11,
                 from /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator4.0.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/CoreFoundation.framework/Headers/CoreFoundation.h:26,
                 from /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator4.0.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/Foundation.framework/Headers/Foundation.h:6,
                 from /Users/rross/Documents/MYPROJECT/_Prefix.pch:6:
/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator4.0.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/UIKit.framework/Headers/UIAccessibilityElement.h:22: error: cannot find interface declaration for 'NSObject', superclass of 'UIAccessibilityElement'
/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator4.0.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/UIKit.framework/Headers/UIAccessibilityElement.h:31: error: expected specifier-qualifier-list before 'BOOL'
/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator4.0.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/UIKit.framework/Headers/UIAccessibilityElement.h:32: error: expected specifier-qualifier-list before 'NSString'
/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator4.0.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/UIKit.framework/Headers/UIAccessibilityElement.h:33: error: expected specifier-qualifier-list before 'NSString'
/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator4.0.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/UIKit.framework/Headers/UIAccessibilityElement.h:34: error: expected specifier-qualifier-list before 'NSString'
In file included from /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator4.0.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/UIKit.framework/Headers/UIResponder.h:10,
                 from /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator4.0.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/UIKit.framework/Headers/UIView.h:9,
                 from /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator4.0.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/UIKit.framework/Headers/UIPickerView.h:10,
                 from /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator4.0.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/UIKit.framework/Headers/UIAccessibilityAdditions.h:12,
                 from /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator4.0.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/UIKit.framework/Headers/UIAccessibility.h:15,
                 from /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator4.0.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/UIKit.framework/Headers/UIKit.h:10,
                 from /Users/rross/Documents/MYPROJECT/src/ross/util/../ui/Comparable.h:9,
                 from /Users/rross/Documents/MYPROJECT/src/ross/datatype/Time.h:11,
                 from /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator4.0.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/CoreFoundation.framework/Headers/CoreFoundation.h:26,
                 from /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator4.0.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/Foundation.framework/Headers/Foundation.h:6,
                 from /Users/rross/Documents/MYPROJECT/_Prefix.pch:6:
/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator4.0.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/UIKit.framework/Headers/UIEvent.h:41: error: cannot find interface declaration for 'NSObject', superclass of 'UIEvent'
/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator4.0.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/UIKit.framework/Headers/UIEvent.h:43: error: expected specifier-qualifier-list before 'NSTimeInterval'
/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator4.0.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/UIKit.framework/Headers/UIEvent.h:49: error: expected specifier-qualifier-list before 'NSTimeInterval'
/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator4.0.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/UIKit.framework/Headers/UIEvent.h:51: error: expected ')' before 'NSSet'
/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator4.0.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/UIKit.framework/Headers/UIEvent.h:52: error: expected ')' before 'NSSet'
/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator4.0.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/UIKit.framework/Headers/UIEvent.h:53: error: expected ')' before 'NSSet'
/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator4.0.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/UIKit.framework/Headers/UIEvent.h:54: error: expected ')' before 'NSSet'
In file included from /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator4.0.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/UIKit.framework/Headers/UIView.h:9,
                 from /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator4.0.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/UIKit.framework/Headers/UIPickerView.h:10,
                 from /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator4.0.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/UIKit.framework/Headers/UIAccessibilityAdditions.h:12,
                 from /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator4.0.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/UIKit.framework/Headers/UIAccessibility.h:15,
                 from /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator4.0.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/UIKit.framework/Headers/UIKit.h:10,
                 from /Users/rross/Documents/MYPROJECT/src/ross/util/../ui/Comparable.h:9,
                 from /Users/rross/Documents/MYPROJECT/src/ross/datatype/Time.h:11,
                 from /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator4.0.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/CoreFoundation.framework/Headers/CoreFoundation.h:26,
                 from /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator4.0.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/Foundation.framework/Headers/Foundation.h:6,
                 from /Users/rross/Documents/MYPROJECT/_Prefix.pch:6:
/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator4.0.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/UIKit.framework/Headers/UIResponder.h:12: error: cannot find interface declaration for 'NSObject', superclass of 'UIResponder'
/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator4.0.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/UIKit.framework/Headers/UIResponder.h:18: error: expected ')' before 'BOOL'
/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator4.0.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/UIKit.framework/Headers/UIResponder.h:19: error: expected ')' before 'BOOL'
/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator4.0.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/UIKit.framework/Headers/UIResponder.h:21: error: expected ')' before 'BOOL'
/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator4.0.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/UIKit.framework/Headers/UIResponder.h:22: error: expected ')' before 'BOOL'
/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator4.0.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/UIKit.framework/Headers/UIResponder.h:24: error: expected ')' before 'BOOL'
/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator4.0.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/UIKit.framework/Headers/UIResponder.h:31: error: expected ')' before 'NSSet'
/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator4.0.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/UIKit.framework/Headers/UIResponder.h:32: error: expected ')' before 'NSSet'
/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator4.0.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/UIKit.framework/Headers/UIResponder.h:33: error: expected ')' before 'NSSet'
/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator4.0.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/UIKit.framework/Headers/UIResponder.h:34: error: expected ')' before 'NSSet'
/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator4.0.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/UIKit.framework/Headers/UIResponder.h:42: error: expected ')' before 'BOOL'
/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator4.0.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/UIKit.framework/Headers/UIResponder.h:42: error: expected ')' before 'SEL'
/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator4.0.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/UIKit.framework/Headers/UIResponder.h:43: error: expected specifier-qualifier-list before 'NSUndoManager'
/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator4.0.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/UIKit.framework/Headers/UIResponder.h:49: error: cannot find interface declaration for 'NSObject'
```

Couple things:

1. I am not using the UIKit frameworks, so why is there uikit related errors?
2. Sorry about the MYPROJECT junk, but the project is confidential right now.

Thank you all in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this, maybe helps

```
#import <Availability.h>

#ifdef __OBJC__
    #import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
    #import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#endif
```

I also suggest you to do all the possible cleaning project stuff and making sure that you selected a correct/existing SDK.

Comment: I cleaned project, but I cannot use `UIKit` at all, so that will not work. I am attempting to make a library that will compile for both Mac OS and iOS.

Comment: If you add UIKit, does it work? In that case just use #if (TARGET_OS_IPHONE | TARGET_IPHONE_SIMULATOR) before the UIKit import

Comment: I solved it, In one of my protocol headers, the default first line is this: `#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>` and I wasn't linking the UIKit framework, thanks!